# How exactly works this Spring Security example?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am pretty new in Spring Security and I have some doubt related the configuration found into a tutorial.

This is the **spring-security.xml** file used to the Spring Security configuration into the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/springLogin" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/doSpringLogin" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/myprofile" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/springHome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/springLogout" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/springLogin?error=true" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/springLogin" login-processing-url="/doSpringLogin"
        default-target-url="/springHome" authentication-failure-url="/springLogin?error=true"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/springLogout" logout-success-url="/springLogin"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.demo.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <constructor-arg name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I it divided into some section. The first one is the  tag content.

It contains something as:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/springLogin" access="permitAll"/>
```

that I think means that the page related to the **/springLogin** resource is accessible to everyone while

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/myprofile" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

means that the resource related to the **/myprofile** resource is accessible only to the logged user (the principal) having a **ROLE_USER** role setted.

Is it this reasoning correct?

Then in the previous configuration file there is:

1) The declaration of the **authenticationManager** bean:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

that I think it is used by Spring to populate the **SecurityContext** with the **Principal** objects (for example all the user of a web application) and with the **Authorities** (what a specific **Principal** can do).

Is this reasoning correct?

This object take as constructor arg a list of **autentication provider** bean that have to provide the **Principal** informations (so for example the role associated to a specific **Principal**)

In this case is provided an implementation of the **DaoAuthenticationProvider** class that take a bean having **name="userDetailsService"** as property, this one:

```
<bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.demo.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
```

that is an instance of the **UserDetailsServiceImpl** class, this one:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(username);
        User user = RegisteryDAO.getUserDAO().getUserByUsername(username);

        if(user == null){
            return null;
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));

        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.
                User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);


        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

So what exactly happen?

Using the debugger it seems to me that when te user try to access to a specific page this **loadUserByUsername()** return the **UserDetails** object related to the logged user that contain the **List** representing the roles associated to the specific logged user (for example the previous **ROLE_USER**)

Then I think that Spring automatically use the

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/myprofile" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

to check if the user have setted the propper role into the previous **List** list.

If it have so forward the request to the controller method that handle this Http Request otherwise avoid that this HttpRequest come to this controller method and show a page that say that the user can't access to this resource.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation of some of the concepts and questions you are asking about.

---

#### `AuthenticationManager`

`AuthenticationManager` is the component responsible for processing the `Authentication` request. The Authentication request might be instance of [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html) for username/password logins.

For other implementations look at [`Authentication` JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

`AuthenticationManager` also has collection of `AuthenticationProvider` implementations. These components are capable of processing specific `Authentication` types and `AuthenticationManager` iterates through them attempting to find one capable of handling the `Authentication` passed to it. If it finds one, it calls it with `Authentication` object presented and returns fully populated `Authentication` object if successful (otherwise `AuthenticationException` is thrown).

---

#### `AuthenticationProvider`

As mentioned above, `AuthenticationProvider` processes certain type of `Authentication` request. For instance the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` will perform following steps when called by `AuthenticationManager`:

- Take the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` passed to it
- Use the `UserDetailsService` service implementation provided to it (in your case it is `UserDetailServiceImpl`) to look up user by username
- Check the password provided in the authentication token against the user using `PasswordEncoder` and `SaltSource`, if specified.
- If the authentication succeeds, returns the populated Authentication object (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in this case), which contains principal, credentials and is marked as [`authenticated`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#isAuthenticated%28%29)
- In case the authentication fails, `AuthenticationException` will be thrown

`DaoAuthenticationProvider` which you are using which is capable of processing `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` requests. So typically form logins, and so on. You can see which types of authentications provider support by looking at its `supports()` method implementation, which in case of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` looks like this:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

---

#### Spring Security Filter Chain

Now let's look at the Security filter chain, as defined by [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html):

> The order that filters are defined in the chain is very important.
>   Irrespective of which filters you are actually using, the order should
>   be as follows:
>
> 1. `ChannelProcessingFilter`, because it might need to redirect to a different protocol
> 2. `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, so a SecurityContext can be set up in the SecurityContextHolder at the beginning of a web request, and
>      any changes to the SecurityContext can be copied to the HttpSession
>      when the web request ends (ready for use with the next web request)
> 3. `ConcurrentSessionFilter`, because it uses the SecurityContextHolder functionality but needs to update the SessionRegistry to reflect
>      ongoing requests from the principal
> 4. Authentication processing mechanisms - `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `CasAuthenticationFilter`,
>      `BasicAuthenticationFilter` etc - so that the `SecurityContextHolder` can
>      be modified to contain a valid Authentication request token
> 5. `The SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware HttpServletRequestWrapper into your
>      servlet container
> 6. `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter`, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      and the request presents a cookie that enables remember-me services to
>      take place, a suitable remembered Authentication object will be put
>      there
> 7. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      an anonymous Authentication object will be put there
> 8. `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an
>      appropriate AuthenticationEntryPoint can be launched
> 9. `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, to protect web URIs and raise exceptions when access is denied

When the user submits login form, `AuthenticationManager` is called at step 4 in the filter chain. In the case of form login it would be handled by [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) which calls the `AuthenticationManager` to process the authentication:

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    // ...
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
```

---

> Using the debugger it seems to me that when te user try to access to a specific page this `loadUserByUsername()` return the `UserDetails`

Actually the `loadUserByUsername()` is called when user authenticates, for instance after submitting login form. If the user is already authenticated this is not called.

> I think that means that the page related to the `/springLogin` resource is accessible to everyone:
>
> ```
> <security:intercept-url pattern="/springLogin" access="permitAll" />
> ```
>
> Then I think that Spring will automatically use following to check if the user has proper role:
>
> ```
> <security:intercept-url pattern="/myprofile" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
> ```

Correct. This process is handled by `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, which extends [`AbstractSecurityInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.html) - core Spring Security component dealing with authorization. If the user is not authenticated or doesn't have the required role an Exception is thrown and handled by the [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html). This filter handles Security exceptions. For instance in case of authentication failure it will redirect user to authentication entry point, e.g. the login page.

---

Internal architecture of Spring Security is pretty nicely described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture). I recommend to take a look at it.